# Adding a validation rule to a Javascript Button

Tags: api, validation

In advance, thank you for your help.

What I am trying to do is to create the following validation rule (whether it will be an actual validation or a javascript API validations, that remains to be determined).

The validation rule or code will have to do the following:

Only allow a user to click on the "NURF" button if AND ONLY if the New Hire Start Date field is populated and not "NULL"

Here is my code as it was before, I just need to add the correct validation rule as outlined above:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}
var Contacts = new sforce.SObject("Contact");
Contacts.Id = '{!Contact.Id}';
Contacts.Recruiting_Status__c = 'NURF Initiated';
Contacts.Workflow_Trigger_FOR_NURF__c = '1';

var result = sforce.connection.update([Contacts]);

if (result[0].success=='false') {
     alert(result[0].errors.message);
} else {
     location.reload(true);
```

Thanks guys and gals.

Answer (score 1):

This seems too easy so I hope i'm not missing something here

Add this validation rule to Contact:

```
ISBLANK(new_hire_start_date__c)
```

when the update happens on the button's javascript, the user gets an error

If this NURF button is on a VF page bound to Contact, you could conditionally render it with a `render="{!NOT(ISBLANK(contact.new_hire_start_date__c))}"`

Comment: Well I understand what the code needs to be (in terms of the qualification/validation) but what I am curious about is where I need to put that code and if I need to preface it with any syntax in order to be a validity argument.

Comment: The Validation rule goes onto the SObject Contact using Setup | Customize | Contacts | Validation Rules